# OAuth and google: I must be missing something?

Tags: oauth

**I'm using thephpleague oauth client library** and everything works fine except for Google authentication. It seems I have to enable my domain somewhere to be able to use Google apps.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/33419?hl=en

This was not helpful indeed as I don't understand what I have to do. Am I obligated to pay for having a working OAuth connection with Google? I don't have a company, I don't need the apps, cloud or any other thing then a working API.

EDIT: to be clear I already wrote my libraries for OAuth and it's all working, it's Google that needs me to do something on domain level.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pay. First of all you need to create a project in the Google Developers Console. Then get your credentials. I don't know which API you are going to access. Have a look at this.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2?csw=1

Additional - This site was very helpful for using the Google Calendar API 
http://www.daimto.com/accessing-google-calendar-with-php-oauth2/#Conclusion

Hope you find what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your effort though it was a misconfiguration as explained in my edit.

Comment: its great that you explained it :)